Guidance of shastra study for non-dvijas
As a non-dvija and a Vaishnava (though I have not received Diksha yet), I am interested in deep and systematic study of shastra. I know Veda can only be studied by the dvija males. I want to know which are the following scriptures can be studied by a non-dvija under a vidwan— Vedanga, Nyaya sutra, Yoga sutra, Vaisheshika sutra, Samkhya sutra, Purva Mimansa sutra, Brahma Sutra, Dharmashastra, Purana, Itihāsa, Pancharatra. Can all of these be studied by non-dvijas or a few of them? What are they? Also, the scriptures which can be studied by non-dvijas, what is the proper order to study them, after learning Sanskrit?

First of all you have BG, you read that and understand that itself is summary of vedic knowledge that is why krishna gave for deprived souls like us. if you want bakthi to be instilled read srimad bhagavatam still more deeper read mahabharatam, mahabharata is called panchama veda.. its had got more knowledge then veda by themselves.. after that if you feel more bhakti read srimad ramayana..

I) With reference to Skanda Purana Vol.18 Book VI, Nagar Kanda, Chapter 239, Verse 31.

जन्मना जायते शूद्रः संस्कारात् द्विज उच्यते।
शापानुग्रहसामर्थ्यं तथा क्रोधः प्रसन्नता ।|31||

janmanā jāyate śūdraḥ saṃskārāddvija ucyate |
śāpānugrahasāmarthyaṃ tathā krodhaḥ prasannatā || 31 ||

A Man is no better than a sudra[शूद्रः] at his birth. He is called Dvija 
[द्विज/Twice Born] due to the consecration[संस्कार]. The ability to curse[शाप]
and to bless[अनुग्रह], the state of being angry[क्रोधः] and pleased[प्रसन्न] and 
the status of being the foremost in all three worlds occur only in Brahmana.

- Skanda Purana: Ch-239, Verse 31.


II) There is one more sloka which is highly interesting and whose origin is from Sanyāsa Dharma Samhitā(सन्यासधर्म संहिता) [Page:24]. This sloka says that everyone is born a Shūdra [ignorant of the path to spiritual knowledge], and by our karma and culture we become Dvijas(द्विज/Twice Born). Eventually, at the final evolvement of Brahma jnāna one is termed as Brāhmana.

जन्मना जायते शूद्रः संस्काराद्द्विज उच्यते |
वेदाभ्यासाद्भवेद्विप्रो ब्रहाज्ञानाच्च ब्राह्मणः ||

janmanā jāyate sudrah samskārāt dvij uchchte |
vedābyāsātbhavetvipro brahmajānācca  brāhmanah ||

Everyone is born Sudra, by accepting Samskara [Purificatory process] 
one becomes a Dvija[Twice Born], By study of Veda one becomes Vipra, 
Knower of Brahman is Brahmana.

- Sanyāsa Dharma Samhitā: Page-24. 


According to the above sūtra anybody can study anything about Hinduism and related Sāstras such as Veda, Vedānga, Shad Darshana (Vaisheshika, Nyāya, Sānkhya, Yoga, Mīmāmsa and Vedānta), Brahma Sūtra, Dharmasāstra, Purāna, Itihāsa, and Pāncharātra.
Beware: Many claim that the above sloka of Sanyāsa Dharma Samhitā is from Atri Smriti(अत्रिस्मृति) but it is not true. The sloka that appears in Atri Smriti [Sloka-140] is given below:

जन्मना ब्राह्मणो ज्ञेय: संस्कारैर्द्विज उच्चते । 
विद्यया याति विप्रत्वं श्रोत्रियत्रिभिरेव च​ ।। 140 ।।

Janmanā Brāhmano jneyat Samskārai Dvija ucchatey।
Vidyā yāti Vipratwam Srotriyastribhireva ca।।

By birth one is known as a Brahmana; and by the purificatory rites, 
he is called a Dvija [twice-born]; he attains to the dignity of a Vipra 
by learning; 
and by these three to that of a Shrotriya [conversant with sacred Knowledge].

- Atri Smriti: Sloka-140


An Example of non-Dvija who learned Sāstras:
Sir John George Woodroffe (aka Arthur Avalon), was a British Orientalist, who was then a judge in a colonial Indian court, hearing a particular case in which he could not come into conclusion. He felt he was deprived of all his senses and could not focus. It was later found that a Tāntric Sādhu in court campus was making a Tāntric Prayoga, known as Bedana Prayoga(भेदन/Act of breaking/dividing/fracture/breach/separating) which is one of Ashta Karma(अष्टकर्म/Eight Acts), on him. This incidence made Woodroffe curious and spent rest of his life studying Indian Tāntrism and came out with the famous book “The Serpent Power”.
Please know that almost all of Tantra Sastra Grantas have been written only in Sanskrit. Exceptionally, John Woodroffe has written Principles of Tantra, which is an English translation of the Bengali work Tantratattva(तंत्रतत्त्व) written by his guru Shivachandra Vidyārnava, mentions that each Krāntā has it's own 64 sets of Shāktāgamas. There are 3 Krāntās, which makes a total of 192 Shāktāgamas.Sir John George Woodroffe extensive and complex
published works on the Tantras, and other Hindu traditions, stimulated
a wide-ranging interest in Hindu philosophy and yoga.

Being a non-Dvija, Sir John George Woodroffe was accepted by his guru (Sri Shivachandra Vidyārnava) and learned, beginning from Sanskrit language, the principles of Sākta and Tantra philosophies and other Sāstras.

This story will definitely inspire and motivate every non-Dvija who wants to take up and study Philosophy of Hinduism.
Your question Also, the scriptures which can be studied by non-dvijas, what is the proper order to study them, after learning Sanskrit?
Study the following in the order they appear:

Sānkhya Darshana(साङ्ख्य दर्शन), authored by Kapila Maharishi(महऋषि कपिल), which delineates an atheistic and strongly dualist exposition of Purusha and Prakriti (परिणामवादम्). Read Samkhya Philosophy [Containing (1) Samkhya-pravachanasutram, with Vritti of Aniruddha, and the Bhasya of Vijnanabhiksu and Extracts from the Vrittisara of Mahadeva Vedantin; (2) Tatvasamasa; (3) Samkhyakarika; (4) Panchasikhasutram] by Nandalal Sihna [Translator].

Yoga Darshana(योग दर्शन), authored by Patanjali Maharishi (महऋषि पतञ्जलि), which is a school emphasizing meditation, contemplation and liberation.

Mukya Dasopanishads(मुख्य दशोपनिषद्): Knowledge of Ten Mukya Upanishads is core to digest Vedānta and the slokas of Bhagavad Gīta effortlessly which are (1) Isā(ईशा), (2) Kena(केन), (3) Katha(कठ), (4) Prasna(प्रस्न), (5) Mundaka(मुण्डक), (6) Māndūkya(माण्डूक्य), (7) Taittirīya(तैत्तिरीय), (8) Aitareya(ऐतरेय), (9) Chāndogya(छान्दोग्य) and (10) Brihadāranyaka(बृहदारण्यक). Read Mukya Upanishad published by Ramakrishna Math iStore.

Vedānta Darshana(वेदान्त दर्शन), authored by Bādrāyana Maharishi (महऋषि भाद्रायण), delineating Philosophical teachings of the Upanishads (mystic or spiritual contemplation within the Vedas) rather than the Brahmanas (instructions for ritual and sacrifice). Read Ādi Sankarāchāryā’s Bhāsyam of Brahma Sutra which is Brahma Sutra Bhasya Hardcover by Sankaracarya (Bhāsyakāra), Swami Gambhirananda (Translator).


Conclusion:
Therefore, no body is Brahmana until Ātmajnānam (आत्मज्ञानम्/ஆத்ம ஞானம்/Self-knowledge) is acquired, so don't hesitate to study whatever you want.
Good Luck!

The example you gave is not good. He did not study Vedhas. He studied Thantras and afaik they both have different adhikaras.

@Vatapatrashaayi , have you read his books? First read them and you will agree with his vast knowledge in Hindu Sastras. As a British, he learnt Sanskrit and mastered it, that itself is an uphill task! This example, involving a foreigner, has been given  for the purpose of inspiration to non-Dvija. I think you have a low opinion about Tantra Sastra. Have you studied Tantras? It has adhikāra to accomplish sādhaka not only Mantra Siddhi but also Moksha(liberation). Please read Kulārnava Tantra to realize this.

What I am saying is for learning Vedha one need to be born as a Dwija and for Thantras that is not required.

@Vatapatrashaayi , Please know that you are completely negating my answer. Please re-read my answer. Point (II) has a reference Sanyāsa Dharma Samhitā which grants adhikāra to Sudras. Similarly, Skanda Purana too allows Sudras. I defended my answer based on scriptural references and never arbitrarily. If you have contention with my references, please comment. Sir John George Woodroffe not only studied Tantra Sastra but aware of Veda too. Since his Guru was a follower of Shakta, majority of Woodroffe's contribution was towards Shakta religion.

The Veda itself boldly declares that the Vedic knowledge is for all. So you can go ahead and read whatever interests you, including the Vedas without any hesitation.
Yajur Veda 26.2

यथेमाँवाचङ्कल्याणीमावदानि जनेभ्यः। ब्रह्मराजन्याभ्याँ शूद्राय चार्याय च स्वाय चारणाय। प्रियो देवानान्दक्षिणायै दातुरिह भूयासमयम्मे कामः समृध्यतामुप मादो नमतु॥


Just as this blessed Word of the Veda I speak for the people, all without exception, Brahmana, Kshatriya, Shudra, Vaishya, master and servant, one’s own and others, so do you too. May I be dear and favourite with the noble divinities and the generous people for the gift of the sacred speech. May this noble aim of mine be fulfilled here in this life. May the others too follow and come my way beyond this life. (Translator - Dr. Tulsi Ram)

Reference -
Online Yajur Veda from Arya Samaj, Chennai

There are already 2 very good answers.
The concept of Dvija is not in the Vedas. It is only in the commentarial tradition like the Dharma Sastras, Puranas etc. These texts are not written by infallible people.

The Dharma Sastras, Puranas and the Angas of the Vedas are full of
diverse opinions on any one point under consideration; for their
composers were under the influence of different gunas.

Srimad Devi Bhagavatam IV.IV
So you can ignore such concepts. The concept that only dvijas can read the Sruti is discriminatory. There is no need to accept this prohibition. In fact the discriminatory nature of such prohibition makes these verses invalid and they shouldn't be followed.
No discrimination

If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
it should not be practiced. It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
and even of Kama.

Kurma Purana I.2.54
Moreover there are explicit statements in scripture that say that all persons are entitled to get knowledge.
The sage Bhrigu said,

‘There is really no distinction between the different orders. The
whole world at first consisted of Brahmanas. Created (equal) by
Brahman, men have, in consequence of their acts, become distributed
into different orders. They that became fond of indulging in desire
and enjoying pleasures, possessed of the attributes of severity and
wrath, endued with courage, and unmindful of the duties of piety and
worship, - these Brahmanas possessing the attributes of passion, -
became Kshatriyas. Those Brahmanas again who, without attending to the
duties laid down for them, became possessed of both the attributes of
Goodness and Passion, and took to the professions of cattle-rearing
and agriculture, became Vaisyas. Those Brahmanas again that became
fond of untruth and injuring other creatures, possessed of cupidity, -
engaged in all kinds of acts for a living, and fallen away from the
purity of behaviour, and thus wedded to the attributes of Darkness,
became Sudras. Separated by these occupations, Brahmanas, falling away
from their order, became members of the other three orders. All the
four orders, therefore, have always the right to the performance of
all pious duties and of sacrifices. Even thus were the four orders at
first created equal by Brahman who ordained for all of them (the
observances disclosed in) the words of Brahma (in the Vedas). Through
cupidity alone, many fell away, and became possessed by ignorance. The
Brahmanas are always devoted to the scripture on Brahma; and mindful
of vows and restraints, are capable of grasping the conception of
Brahma. Their penances therefore never go for nothing. They amongst
them are not Brahmanas that are incapable of understanding that every
created thing is Supreme Brahma.

(Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CLXXXVIII)
The famous Rishi Yajnavalkya continued,

’ .. All orders of men are
Brahmanas. All are sprung from Brahma. All men utter Brahma. Aided by
an understanding that. I inculcated this science teaching of Prakriti
and Purusha. Indeed this whole universe is Brahma. From the mouth of
Brahma sprung the Brahmanas; from his arms, sprung the Kshatriyas;
from his navel, the Vaisysa; and from his feet, the Sudras. All the
orders, (having sprung in this way) should not be regarded as
pilfering from one another. Impelled by ignorance, all men meet with
death and attain, O King, to birth that is the cause of acts. Divested
of knowledge, all orders of men, dragged in terrible ignorance, fall
into varied orders of being due to the principles that flow from
Prakriti. For this reason, all should, by every means, seek to
acquire knowledge. I have told thee that every person is entitled to
strive for its acquisition. One that is possessed of knowledge is a
Brahmana. Others, (viz., Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas and Sudras) are
possessed of knowledge. Hence this science of emancipation is always
open to them all.

(Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCXIX)

Maheshwara said, ‘..Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor
learning, nor offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring
upon one the regenerate status. Verily, the conduct is the only
ground. All Brahmanas in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of
conduct. A Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as
possessed of the status of a Brahmana. The status of a Brahma, O
auspicious lady [Uma], is equal wherever it exists. Even this is my
opinion. He, indeed, is a Brahmana in which the status of Brahma
exists – that condition which is bereft of attributes and which has no
stain attached to it. The boon giving Brahma, when he created all
creatures, himself said that the distribution of human beings in four
orders dependent on birth is only for purposes of classification.'

Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII
